# How can I assign the Commerce Product SKU as the Path Alias?

Tags: commerce, path-aliases

We would like to automatically assign the Path Alias for each new Product as /products/sku.

How can we do this, either from the URL Alias admin UI or via Rule or programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) should give you enough flexibility to do that.

Once your "product" content type has a `commerce_product_reference` field linked to it (let's call it "field_product"), all fields attached to your "product variation type" should be available as tokens like this:

`[node:field-product:product-id]` or if you created a specific field to store the value `[node:field-product:field-sku]`.

You probably know it but patterns can be configured from here : `admin/config/search/path/patterns`.